# Peewee: Add a column and define order within schema using `AFTER`

Tags: peewee

I'd like to use playhouse migrator to make changes to my db schema.

I'd like to add a column to a database but with `AFTER` in sql statement so that I may define the column order in the table.

Is this possible with Peewee/Playhouse migrator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no trigger support in Peewee.  In 2015 [the author stated](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/786#issuecomment-163095965) that

> I do not plan on supporting triggers at this time.

However, Peewee has "[Signal support](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#signal-support)".

```python
from playhouse.signals import Model, post_save

class MyModel(Model):
    data = IntegerField()

@post_save(sender=MyModel)
def on_save_handler(model_class, instance, created):
    put_data_in_cache(instance.data)
```

Perhaps, this could be used as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the schema migrator does not support the AFTER clause. You are left with subclassing the relevant migrator class, or using a custom field-class and implementing a `ddl()` method on the field, which includes the AFTER portion.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the field with your custom ones and override the sort_key to a large number to ensure they are always pushed to the end.
This is definitely not the best way, but it works.

```
class dbCustomDateTime(dbDateTime): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Defining the sort key to ensure that even if this is used in a baseclass,
        # this column will go to the end of the table
        self._sort_key = 100, 100
```